# Vue.js not setting data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to do some simple form validation using Laravel 5.3 and Vue.js.

Laravel controller:

```
 public function test(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'date' => 'required'
        ]);
...
    }
```

Vue data:

```
let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',

data: {
        submitted: false,
        errors: [],
        post: {
               name: '',
               date: '',
              },
},
```

Vue post:

```
Vue.http.post('url', post).then((response) => {
    // form submission successful, reset post data and set submitted to true
    app.post = {
        name: '',
        date: '',
    };

    // clear previous form errors
    app.$set('errors', '');

    app.submitted = true;

}, (response) => {
    // form submission failed, pass form  errors to errors array
    console.log(response.data.name); //"The Name field is required."
    app.$set('errors', response.data); // TypeError
});
```

I'm getting

> TypeError: can't assign to properties of (new String("errors")): not
>   an object

with `app.$set('errors', response.data);`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How you method that trigger `Vue.http.post` looks like ? `Vue.http` is for global usage, there is a `this.$http.post` which refers to Vue instance, so consider about correct use case.Btw this promise looks a bit weird to me, what shoud second method that accept response do ?

Comment: @BelminBedak, `this.$http.post` yields the same results.

Comment: Okay, what about promise here ? There could be 2 scenarios `.then()` when promise is fulfilled, and `.catch()` when there is an issue.What the second method with parameter response do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [vm.$set(object, key, value)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set), you're trying to add a property to *the string* 'errors' using `response.data` as the key.

The correct syntax is `app.$set(app, 'errors', response.data)` but `app.errors = response.data` should work equally well.

Comment: Ah! I was originally using  `this` where object is not required:      `this.$set('errors', response.data)` Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Both [`this.$set` and `Vue.set`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/observer/index.js#L191)(they are the same thing) require the target object to be passed as the first parameter.

Comment: You're right... looks like that was from v0.12 `obj.$set(key, value)` http://012.vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html#Adding_and_Deleting_Properties